# API to get only SCP enabled region in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

Is there a way to get only the SCP enabled regions for an account/user. We have "DescribeRegions"(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeRegions.html) action which gives all the enabled regions for an account but not SCP enabled regions. Please let me know if there is a way to get SCP enabled regions through an API/CLI?. Thanks

Comment: How do you define "SCP-enabled regions"? From my knowledge, SCPs use policies, so it would be a matter of having to interpret the contents of the policies, rather than just looking at what regions are enabled. Do you have a reference to such a concept?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I have to get SCP enabled regions then call the resources wrt enabled regions.

Comment: I found a reference here: [Example service control policies - AWS Organizations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_example-scps.html#example-scp-deny-region) It looks like you would need to look through these types of policies to look for the contents of `aws:RequestedRegion`, paying attention to  `StringEquals` or `StringNotEquals`.

Comment: To do this you'll need permission to retrieve SCPs from the organization root, identify the policies (plural!) that apply to a given account, parse those policies, and identify the regions that apply to a particular resource (and different resources -- EC2 versus IAM, for example, may have different policies). You should probably also consider permissions boundaries. Unless you're _extremely_ familiar with IAM, this is going to be an extremely time-consuming problem, with lets of opportunity for mistakes.

Comment: What is the _real_ problem that you're trying to solve? As in the business use-case.

Comment: @Parsifal, I want to get only SCP enabled regions and call the resources wrt those regions. Finally, I found out that there is no API to get SCP enabled regions.

Comment: Well, I've given you the general outline of how to do that. Good luck.